# playing video in Centos using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I am following this tutorial from openCV to play back a video on centos .

[openCV tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

see the code below , it doesn't throw any errors but does not show any videos being played.  If I use the image display program it works fine which tells me the X11 forwarding part is working fine .

```
[root@hadoop1 basic-motion-detection]# more demo1.py
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/admin/example_02.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.startWindowThread()
    cv2.namedWindow("preview")
    cv2.imshow('preview',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Video playback over X11 forwarding? Won't work. Was never designed to work.

Comment: so opencv is not certified over Linux for vidoes? I see lots of examples for displaying images on Linux using openCV and  none for videos, or is there another way to playback videos using openCV under Linux other than X11 forwarding?

Comment: X11 **forwarding** can't play videos, because videos are typically played through X extensions (like xv, or some sort of OpenGL) which can't be transported through network. So, locally, video with X11 is no problem, but forwarding video through network is.

Comment: so looking at my code can you advise how can I run it on Linux?

Comment: I will add to my comment as  I don't even know is it possible to manipulate and view videos using openCV on Linux ? after all the product comes for this platform .

Comment: hi Marcus I am displaying  openCV image also locally vi X11 window, so how can I display video locally ?

Comment: does that imply there's no X11 forwarding involved?